# ruby - bzip files

Tags: ruby, compression, zip, bzip2

I want to compress the files in ruby.
for example I have file:

```
base_1.txt
base_2.txt
base_3.txt
```

I want these files compressed to `base.bz`

How can I do it in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this library:

https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a standard library function for ruby that performs bz2 operations.  There are a few libraries like the one described above from 3rd party.

Ruby also facilitates using the operating systems shell. Assuming Linux:
You could call the system call:

system("bzip2 base_1.txt")

or the equivalents:

`bzip2 base_1.txt`

%x[ bzip2 base_1.txt ]